# Error converting char[2] to unsigned short?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, byte, short, endianness

### Edit:

After reading the comments, thanks to @M.M and @AnttiHaapala I fixed my code but still got incorrect outputs...

**New Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char * myChar;
    myChar = new char[2];
    myChar[1] = 0x00;
    myChar[0] = 0xE0;
    unsigned short myShort;
    myShort = ((myChar[1] << 8) | (myChar[0]));
    std::cout << myShort << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
65504
```

or if you reverse the order

```
57344
```

### Old Post:

So I have a two byte value that I am reading from a file and would like to convert to a unsigned short so I can use the numerical value.

**Example code:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char myChar[2];
    myChar[1] = 'à';
    myChar[0] = '\0';
    unsigned short myShort;
    myShort = ((myChar[1] << 8) | (myChar[0]));
    std::cout << myShort << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
40960
```

But `à\0` or `E0 00` should have a value of 224 as an unsigned two byte value?

Also very interesting...

**This code:**

```
include <iostream>
int main() {
    char * myChar;
    myChar = "\0à";
    unsigned short myShort;
    myShort = ((myChar[1] << 8) | (myChar[0]));
    std::cout << myShort << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
49920
```

Comment: Your question is not about C

Comment: Read about little- and big-endian numbers. x86 processors are little-endian.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's clearly c++ code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that is why I deleted the [C] tag...

Comment: Yes I understand that. That is why I have `00 E0` or `\0à ` as my input. I also tried flipping the character values to `à\0` and got a result of `65475`.

Comment: The output of 40960 indicates that you used character code of 160, which is `à` for me.

Comment: @M.M oh yeah i meant the alpha character? For some reason when I paste it it gets converted to that character? Strange...

Comment: Please show the output of `printf("%d\n",  'à');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** The original code has a complicating factor in that the source is UTF-8 encoded.  Please check edit history of this answer to see my comments on that. However I think that is not the main issue you are asking about, so I have changed my answer to just address the edit.  To avoid UTF-8 conversion issues, use `'\xE0'` instead of `'à'`.

---

Regarding the edited code:

```
char * myChar;
myChar = new char[2];
myChar[1] = 0x00;
myChar[0] = 0xE0;
unsigned short myShort;
myShort = ((myChar[1] << 8) | (myChar[0]));
std::cout << myShort << std::endl;
```

The range of `char` (on your system) is `-128` through to `127`.  This is common.  You write `myChar[0] = 224;`.  (`0xE0` is an `int` literal with value `224`).

This is an *out of range conversion*, which causes *implementation-defined behaviour*.  Most commonly, implementations will define this to adjust modulo 256 until the value is in range. So you end up with the same result as:

```
myChar[0] = -32;
```

Then the calculation `(myChar[1] << 8) | myChar[0]` is `0 | (-32)`, which is `-32`.  Finally, you convert to `unsigned short`.  This is another *out-of-range conversion*, because the range of `unsigned short` is `[0, 65535]` on your system.

However, out-of-range conversion to unsigned type is well-defined to adjust modulo `65536` in this case, so the result is 65536 - 32 = `65504`.

---

Reversing the order performs `((-32) << 8) | 0`.  Left-shifting a negative value causes *undefined behaviour*, although on your system it has manifested itself as doing `-32 * 256`, giving `-8192`. Converting that to `unsigned short` gives 65536 - 8192 = `57344`.

---

If you are trying to get `224` from the first example, the simplest way to do this is to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`.  Then `myChar[0]` will hold the value `224` instead of the value `-32`.

Answer (score 1):

Use unsigned types for bit level manipulation.

For example, on a computer with 8-bit byte, and where `char` is signed, `myChar[0] = 0xE0` results in a negative value. Which is *sign extended* when it's used in an expression.

Conversely, to avoid problems, use signed types for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When you store the character into `myChar`, you're storing it big-endian:  The high byte first, then the low byte.  When you read the individual bytes out, you are reading them as little-endian:  low byte first, high byte second (shifted by 8, or multiplied by 256).  This is why you get such a large value.

```
myShort = (myChar[0] * 256) + myChar[1];
```

will give you the expected answer.